# Checkboxlist selected item cannot be clear in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a form that contains of a gridview and a hidden panel inside an updatepanel.
When I click on the gridview header, I will use ModalPopupExtender from ajax to populate the hidden panel and show a checkboxlist for users to chose and then save.

The problem that I'm having is, the selected item from checkboxlist cannot be cleared.
For example, I selected first item and click save. After that ModalPopupExtender will be closed. If I click on the gridview header again, when the checkboxlist is populated, the previous selected first item clearly showed that it wasn't selected. Then I select second item from the checkboxlist to save, but this time the system will detect that the first item still selected. So on second save, it will show that I had selected first and second item.

I tried to loop all items and set selected =false but it didn't work. I also tried the below codes but no luck. Please help.

CheckBoxList.EnableViewState = false;
CheckBoxList.ClearSelection();

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
    function checkListClear() {
        var chk = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1');
        var checkBoxArray = chk.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.length; i++)
                {
                    if (checkBoxArray[i].checked) {                          
                       checkBoxArray[i].checked = false;
                   }
                }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hi Nadee. I got the below error message. 
Unable to get value of the property 'getElementsByTagName': object is null or undefined.
    
And I'm using the below codes for the javascript part.
var chk = contentWindow.document.getElementById("<%=cblStep.ClientID%>");
          var checkBoxArray = chk.getElementsByTagName('input');

Comment: Did you test this in IE? After you changed the script is it wokring now?

Comment: Hi Nadee. I modified the code and became like this.
var chk = contentWindow.document.getElementById("<%=cblStep.ClientID%>");
          var checkBoxArray = chk.getElementsByTagName('input');
          for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.length; i++) {
              if (checkBoxArray[i].checked) {
                  checkBoxArray[i].checked = false;
              }
          }

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript function to call on the button you click to open the ModalPopupExtender
Add it to OnClientClick